# How did they do those effects in http://artofflightmovie.com/?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand how they did those effects in http://artofflightmovie.com/ with no success so far. I am not even sure what to google for for help. Could any one ellaborate on it and perhaps put links to plugins\tutorials\other websites doing the same thing?

There is already a similar question, but it didn't help me a bit ^^

- [Custom scroll bar behavior in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630450/custom-scroll-bar-behavior-in-javascript)

Comment: Use the developer tools of your favourite browser to look at the page source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the answers here so far are spot on and cover various pieces of the execution. Joseph's post about how we 'contained' and 'maneuvered' the site are dead-on, and those mentioning jQuery accurately depict our heavy reliance on it :)

With that said, the other concept of moving along a non-linear path was probably the most difficult part. We literally used an Illustrator file that was setup like a piece of graph paper and drew a bezier path that reflected the movement we wanted from the scrollbar. Then we 'downsampled' the path by converting the curved lines into a bunch of straight lines that represented the curve (similar to downsampling audio waveforms) to keep performance/speed high. We took those coordinates, gave them to our designer, and he created a gigantic design file and literally designed each content section at the designated 'stop' points. Next we mapped each coordinate along the path to a percentage value of the scroll position. We stored these values in a JavaScript array. Lastly we wrote some JS functions that we pipe the scroll position through to determine how to offset the positioning of the site 'container'. (It basically 'tweens' between each coordinate allowing us very fine/precise values at any given scroll percentage) The scroll functionality is handled by a tall div that basically sets our document height to force a scrollbar, and we just read it's position during a Scroll Event and slide the container around to where it should be using the above mentioned functions.

The parallax effect is achieved by applying a percentage of the position offset (what we use to move the container around) and applying it to the sub-containers of the various content sections. This makes the subcontainers move slower or faster than the background, but on the same motion path.

Lastly, the little snowboarders and helicopters (which have CSS3 rotations in addition to x,y movement in some browsers!) are positioned by using a simliar array of 'start' and 'end' positions and tweening between them based on the scroll percentage.

I'll leave it at that to keep this from turning into a book, but I'd be happy to elaborate on specifics if you're interested.

**Full disclosure**: I was lead developer on the site. I'm not posting to 'toot my own horn' or anything like that, just to be helpful and provide assistance to a fellow tinkerer. I come here a lot to dig through and get insight from others. (many, many thanks to those who have helped us!)  Also, shameless plug, but the film is breath-taking... go rent it if you haven't yet, you won't be sorry. :)

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty cool website ;)

Basically using some javascript you can detect how far a person has scrolled. Considering the amount of scrolling you can move the contents of your webpage around if their position is absolute.

There are a couple of jQuery plugins that allow you to do simular stuff although I'm not sure you can "scroll through" a sequence of coordinates.

Here are a couple of jQuery plugins that helps you get simular effects:

- http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/
- http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/
- http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo
- http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

I just picked a couple I'm familiar with but there are many plugins that are alike.

**edit:**

Decided to add some more simular websites for your pleasure.

- http://www.activatedrinks.com
- http://www.beetle.de
- http://www.nikebetterworld.com

Answer (score 2):

the whole page is an "overlay" - a full width and height wrapper `<div>`. sort of how modal windows do their "full page shadow" effect and have a small div float inside. the whole page content is in that wrapper. the scroll path is a script. the script captures the body scroll and moves the contents of the div accordingly to the positions provided by the script. with a body long enough to be scrollable (which cannot be seen since the wrapper covers the whole page), it's as if you are scrolling sideways, upwards etc.

an analogy is a modal window. the wrapper is the full-page shade. the modal window is the content. and notice how modal windows stick to the middle? that's using a script to calculate it's position to stay in the middle by moving the modal window down, relative to the page's top. but in that website's case, they move in different directions.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem too complicated.

Using the `.scroll(function() {})` in jQuery you listen for a scroll event. When triggered you set the position style (left, top) of the content `div` to give the appearance of moving sideways instead of down.

I guess you'll need `overflow:none` property on the `div` to prevent users from scrolling over the area you don't want them to see.

Sounds like a lot of effort for a clunky user interface in my opinion.

Comment: doesn't just move sideways, even moves upwards when scrolling down. amazing website!

Comment: You can move it wherever you like with `left` and `top` css on an `absolute` positioned element.