# jquery/javascript mouse wheel scrolling horizontal/vertical

Tags: jquery, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

i'm working on site like http://artofflightmovie.com/, i know how to achieve that effect if you click on menu item and it will automaticly scroll you to that element, but a don't know ho to do the scrolling with mouse wheel.

If someone know about some plugin or any tip?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923136/how-did-they-do-those-effects-in-http-artofflightmovie-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been seeking for that, there is actually a plugin to do it :
jq plugin : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel
demo : http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos
Hope this helps !