# Move background-image position along a path when scrolling

Tags: jquery, animation, background, parallax

This is my first post to I apoligise if its not perfectly put.

Essentially I am trying to achieve the same or similar effect as has been brilliantly utilised on the Red Bull Art of Flight movie website:

http://artofflightmovie.com/

i.e the background-image moving along a path of co-ordinates as the user scrolls down the page. I'm not to worried about the content animations at the moment just the background animation.

I am able to do the basic, move the background from a to b animation but am stauck on what to do when i want to go from b to c, c to d etc etc.

I have tried using the openly available:

```
$('.bg').scroll(function(){
   var x = $(this).scrollTop();
   $(this).css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/10)+'px');
});
```

This allows me to set the background position change when the user scrolls but I am not sure how I would then set the next animation. My initial thought was to use an else if but this was not successful.

The artofflightmovie.com example sets an array of background-position px measurements which are then read like a timeline.

I'm ok with what I want the CSS to be however my knowledge of jQuery is not up to a level that I can overcome the issues i'm having.

I have also taken the source of the Art Of Flight page and attempted to created a simplified version to build on but again to no great avail.

Any help, would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you stuck? What's your code so far? Questions questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did they do those effects in http://artofflightmovie.com/?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923136/how-did-they-do-those-effects-in-http-artofflightmovie-com)

Comment: How sure are you that it is a background image and not a number of absolutely positioned elements including one very large image? Seems you may be able to accomplish this with an array of x,y pairs to move towards. Once the destination is reached, the x,y pair is moved to the end of the array and you move towards the next. Probably simpler in theory than in application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys.

I actually found the sort of thing I was after here: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Great jQuery plugin that uses the canvas element to render a path and jQuery control the scroll along it. Events/functions can also be triggered at every way point.